# How to build and start containers on multiple docker machines

Tags: docker

I have to rebuild an image and stop/run new containers on a large number of docker machines. What is the best way to do this in an automated way?

Right now I am doing

`eval $(docker-machine env docker-host-1)`

`docker stop some-container`

`docker build -t my-image .`

`docker run -d my-image`

for each host but this is very time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Building

Build the image only once and push it to a registry. You can use the [public registry of Docker](https://hub.docker.com/) or use a [private one](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/).

```
docker push $DOCKERHUB_USER/my-image:latest
```

Then you just use that image from your docker hosts:

```
docker run -d $DOCKERHUB_USER/my-image:latest
```

## Upgrade

You need an orchestrator to ease management. Take a look to [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/), [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), [Openshift](https://www.openshift.org/) or [Rancher](http://rancher.com/). In a  nutshell, the orchestrator will schedule and run your containers on the docker hosts. If you want to upgrade, just create the image with a different tag and change it in the service definition. The orchestrator will roll out the upgrade for you.

Comment: Building on this, if you use Docker Cloud for your registry, it has a nice autobuild functionality. Push to github and it triggers a build: https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/repos/
https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/automated-build/